# Game Over Screen - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I'm building a simple SpriteKit game. I would like to add a Game Over Screen, with a button to return to the main screen. But it seems it's not very easy to do with SpriteKit.

I previously had a "Back" button on the main game view which stayed there when the Game Over view loaded. Bur using it and playing again would make the fps drop. So, its there any way to add a button to a `SKScene`? For example like creating a View Controller in Storyboard and adding the button there, then make the Scene appear there...

If you need any code or anything, just tell me and I'll post it. Thanks!

Comment: Adding a UIButton to a SKView as a subview is not an option, right? The FPS drops then?

Comment: Well, at least from the Storyboard, it happened. I think ARC was just retaining the contents but I didn't know how to release them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to subclass `SKNode` to make a button in `SpriteKit`.

Simple example:

```
@interface MyButton : SKSpriteNode

@property (nonatomic, readonly) SEL action;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) id target;

- (void)setTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

@end

@implementation SKButton

- (void)setTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action 
{
    _target = target;
    _action = action;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, touchPoint)) 
    {
        objc_msgSend(_target, _action);
    }
}

@end
```

Or you can just create a `UIButton` and add it to the `SKView`:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[skView addSubview:button];
```

I haven't experienced any performance hit but my test project is not complex.

Comment: Thanks, I'll save this for future projects/ideas! :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a simple solution that works for me (for now at least). Here it is: http://meghagulati.com/2014/01/20/simple-parse-tutorial-with-sprite-kit-game/

The author creates a node and then when the node is touched, the game is loaded again. Code can be seen in its website.

Comment: He or she is using SKLabel.